Spring Data R2DBC: Saving Department with Empty Employee List (Unsupported array type)
I'm encountering an error while saving a Department object with Spring Data R2DBC. My Department model has an employees property that can hold a list of Employee objects. However, when I try to create a new department with an empty employee list, I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported array type: io.spring.graphql.employeedemo2.model.Employee

Code Snippet:
Department.class
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "department_tbl")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @Column("department_name")
    private int id;

    @Column("department_name")
    private String name;

    private List<Employee> employees;

    public Department(int id, String name, List<Employee> employees){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.employees = new ArrayList<>();
    }

AddDepartmentInput.class
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AddDepartmentInput {

    private int id;
    private String name;

}

@MutationMapping
public Mono<Department> createDepartment(@Argument AddDepartmentInput departmentInput) {
    return Mono.just(departmentInput)
        .map(dptInput -> {
            Department department = new Department();
            department.setId(dptInput.getId());
            department.setName(dptInput.getName());
            department.setEmployees(new ArrayList<>()); // Empty list initialization
            return department;
        })
        .flatMap(department -> departmentRepository.save(department));
}

and this is my schema.graphqls
type Employee {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    salary: Float
    departmentId: ID!
}

type Department {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    employees: [Employee]
}

type Mutation {
    createDepartment(departmentInput: AddDepartmentInput ):Department
}

input AddDepartmentInput {
    id:ID!
    name:String
}

Context:

I'm using Spring Data R2DBC for data persistence.
I want to allow creating departments initially without any associated employees.

Question:
How can I effectively save a Department object with an empty employees list using Spring Data R2DBC? Are there recommended approaches for handling empty lists within models?

Spring Data R2dbc does not support the one to many relation as JPA and Spring Data JPA, so you could have to separate the Department and Employee in different tables.
@Table(name = "department_tbl")
record Department(...) {}

@Table(name = "employee_tbl")
record Employee(@Column Integer departmentId, ....){}

And when you are using Spring GraphQL, it is better to use different model classes to present the GraphQL input,etc, do not mix the data model classes.
Check my example using Spring Webflux/Spring GraphQL/Spring Data R2dbc: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/tree/master/spring-graphql-webflux
